# ffmpeg не хочет читать полный путь файла субтитра, в чем дело?

Tags: ffmpeg

Всем здравствуйте! Как правильно оформить вывод от диска до пути файла в субтитре?
Исходный:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "F:\Cinema\Output\1015471\1015471.mkv" -map_metadata -1 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vsync 1 -async 1 -color_primaries 1 -color_trc 1 -colorspace 1 -vf subtitles=1015471.srt,scale="'w=if(gt(a,16/9),1280,-2):h=if(gt(a,16/9),-2,720)'" -ab 196k -maxrate 2000k -bufsize 6400k -acodec aac -ac 2 -ab 128k -f mp4 -movflags +faststart -preset ultrafast "F:\Cinema\Output\1015471\ss.mp4"
```

subtitles=1015471.srt - работает, если прописать subtitles="F:\Disk\1015471.srt" не работает
пишет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как бороться данную ситуацию?

Comment: Возможно, экранируйте слэш? `"F:\\Disk\\1015471.srt"` Или просто замените на другой `"F:/Disk/1015471.srt"`

Comment: @andreymal такая же проблема, оба варианта не помогли.

Comment: мне кажется тут ошибка порядка опций, судя по самой первой строке, он читает путь как параметр размеров

Comment: попробуйте `subtitles="F\:\\Disk\\1015471.srt"` экранировать нужно и двоеточие, так как это разделитель параметров